# What's the difference between USB_MASS_STORAGE and USB_FILE_STORAGE and how to best use it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel, embedded-linux

In Linux kernel 3.4, what's the difference between USB_MASS_STORAGE and USB_FILE_STORAGE?

I would like to have an embedded device running kernel 3.4 to show a mount point when connected to a PC. This mount point should be writable on the PC and then readable on the embedded device from memory. In other words, the embedded device local storage should be in memory (such as ramfs). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in Linux kernel 3.18 `CONFIG_USB_MASS_STORAGE` is replacement for `USB_FILE_STORAGE`:

> The Mass Storage Gadget acts as a USB Mass Storage disk drive. As its
>   storage repository it can use a regular file or a block device (in
>   much the same way as the "loop" device driver), specified as a module
>   parameter or sysfs option. This driver is a replacement for now
>   removed File-backed Storage Gadget (g_file_storage).

So far I could successfully expose `/dev/mmcblk0p1` (am335x SoC) to Windows using `CONFIG_USB_MASS_STORAGE`:

```
modprobe g_mass_storage file=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```